# how to change value in ng-repeat and show out of ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

```
{{$$addFunc='isAdd'}}
<span ng-repeat="listItem in stmt.content">
    <span ng-switch on="listItem.meta.category">
        <span ng-switch-when="plain" ng-bind-template="{{listItem.content}}">
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="link">
            <a href="{{listItem.content.lnk}}">{{listItem.content.cap}}</a>
        </span>
        <span ng-switch-when="list" ng-init="{{$$addFunc='isInsert'}}">{{$$addFunc}}</span>
    </span>
</span>
{{$$addFunc}}
```

How to modify the code to make $$addFunc is 'isInsert'?

Comment: Change `<span ng-switch on="listItem.meta.category">` to `<span ng-switch="listItem.meta.category">`

Comment: Also you should explain better. I have no idea what exactly is happening here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need {{ }} interpolation to set the value of a variable.  `ng-init` takes a plain expression:

`ng-init="$$addFunc='isInsert'"`

---

The other problem you'll have updating `$$addFunc` is that `ng-switch` creates a [child scope](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).  So that this scope can update `$$addFunc`, you should move it into an object:

```
$scope.operation = {
  $$addFunc: 'isAdd'
};
```

And update it like this:

```
<span ng-switch-when="list" ng-init="operation.$$addFunc='isInsert'">
```

Here is a working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Alypsqu1bSCwCqko4F8m?p=preview